# InvalidCredentialsError("the specified credentials were rejected by the server")

Tags: python, python-3.x, winrm

I am unable to get WinRM session in a python script.

Client - 2012 R2

Client is a Domain member. user01 is a non domain account and member of Local administrators group.
I have tried setting winrm basic or kerberos to false.
I even tried with local administrator account but still same error.
Both ntlm and ssl were not working.

After setting LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy registry to 1 this works:

```
p = Protocol(
    endpoint='https://X.X.X.X:5986/wsman',
    transport='ntlm',
    username='user01',
    password='admin@123',
    server_cert_validation='ignore')

p.open_shell()
```

SSL is not working:

```
p = Protocol(
    endpoint='https://X.X.X.X:5986/wsman',
    transport='ssl',
    username='user01',
    password='admin@123',
    server_cert_validation='ignore')

p.open_shell()
```

Error:

> InvalidCredentialsError("the specified credentials were rejected by the server")
>   winrm.exceptions.InvalidCredentialsError: the specified credentials were rejected by the server